# Passing Firebase data from RecyclerView to another Custom Dialog with RecyclerView - Android

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, customdialog

I'm a newbie and I cannot pass the data of a recyclerview from a custom dialog to the current clicked recyclerview inside the activity.

I made the TextView from my Adapter static to try and pass it on but it ends up on the last data of the recyclerview in the activity.

### This is from the first recyclerview where you can see it on the MainActivity.class

```
public class RecyclerWithDiaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerWithDiaAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
ArrayList<RWDModel> stringArrayList;

public static Dialog dialog;

public RecyclerWithDiaAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<RWDModel> stringArrayList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.stringArrayList = stringArrayList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_recy_with_dia, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    RWDModel positional = stringArrayList.get(position);

    holder.header_title.setText(positional.header);
    holder.detail_title.setText(positional.detail);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return stringArrayList.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    static TextView header_title;
    TextView detail_title;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        header_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.header_title);
        detail_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detail_title);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(detail_title.getContext());
            }
        });
    }
}

private static void showDialog(Context context) {
    dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_recycler);

    Button btndialog = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btndialog);
    btndialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    RecyclerView recyclerView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    AdapterRe adapterRe = new AdapterRe(context, RecyWithDia.strings);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterRe);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

    dialog.show();
   }
}
```

### And this is the custom dialog with recyclerview

```
public class AdapterRe extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterRe.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private String[] myImageNameList;

public AdapterRe(Context context, String[] myImageNameList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.myImageNameList = myImageNameList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_recycler, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.name.setText(myImageNameList[position]);
    holder.title.setText("For ");
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return myImageNameList.length;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView name;
    TextView title;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                RecyclerWithDiaAdapter.dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code that doesn't work the way you expect.